# AS3 drawing line with brush PNG images pattern

Tags: actionscript-3, drawing

This functionality exists in desktop programs such as Adobe Illustrator or Painter.

You can select a brush that is a pattern of images. Starting to paint on canvas displays a line (or any pattern) created from a set of images of different sizes and rotations.   Approximately how I portrayed in the picture (the red line is a path of the brush motion).

[image]

Is there already a library for this effect, or how it can best be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen for `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN` on your drawing canvas and once it fires, add a `Event.ENTER_FRAME` to begin drawing. The drawing itself is pretty straightforward - on every frame you take the mouseX and mouseY values and add the PNG image on the canvas in the exact place with any transformations (scaling, rotation, alpha) for that particular image. Here's a simple example:

```
private var PatternPNG:Class;
private var canvas:Sprite;

private function init() {
  canvas = new Sprite();
  addChild(canvas);
  canvas.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
  canvas.graphics.drawRect(0,0,CANVAS_WIDTH,CANVAS_HEIGHT);
  canvas.graphics.endFill();
  canvas.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
}
private function onMouseDown(e:Event):void
{
  canvas.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
  canvas.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);
  canvas.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
}
private function onMouseUp(e:Event):void
{
  canvas.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
  canvas.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);
  canvas.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
}
private function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void
{
  var patternPiece:DisplayObject = new PatternPNG();
  patternPiece.rotation = Math.random() * 360;
  patternPiece.alpha = Math.random();
  patternPiece.scaleX = patternPiece.scaleY = 0.2 + Math.random() * 0.8;
  patternPiece.x = mouseX;
  patternPiece.y = mouseY;
  canvas.addChild(patternPiece);
}
```

Comment: Be careful, adding children in an enterFrame loop will soon fill your memory with sprites. You should make a copy of your canvas in a bitmapData (BitmapData.draw()), display it in a Bitmap and empty the canvas on each iteration.

Comment: I would suggest drawing canvas to Bitmap in `onMouseUp` (after a stroke), because drawing on each frame might be resource expensive as well. Or at least at some points (e.g., when canvas has 100 children or more).