# Fill picture with color

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

I'm asking about ActionScript 3 code to fill attached picture with red color, then giving me message `trace("100% painted");` when totally filled, and adding button to clear it again.

[image: fish]

Comment: Do you mean for someone to paint it like a coloring book, or for the application to fill it in animated way?

Comment: yes, someone to paint it.

Comment: go here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595936/as3-drawing-line-with-brush-png-images-pattern, you should browse the forums better.. it took me 2 seconds

Comment: @joshua That involves drawing with a pattern, whereas this involves painting within the shape and signaling when all area has been filled.  Also, [Stack Overflow is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum/92110#92110).